# how to query information from the /proc filesystem?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, debian, proc

how would I begin to do this? I want to write a shell script file that would allow me to pull information from the proc filesystem. Information like PID, state of processes, etc...

a short code demo to put me in the right direction would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The `/proc` filesystem is simply a set of data exposed as files, so you can operate on them like you do any other file, with `cat`, `grep`, etc.

One example of a thing I do in my shell configuration is operate a little differently depending on the process that started my shell.  So I can write something like this:

```
case $(readlink /proc/$PPID/exe) in
    *tmux)
        echo "using tmux";;
    *mate-terminal)
        echo "using the terminal";;
    *)
        echo "maybe a VT";;
esac
```

You can look at the files with a normal tool like `less` and see what you'd like to get out of them.

Comment: Your caim applies to the Linux procfs but not to the original procfs written by Roger Faulkner. So please mention that your answer does not apply to procfs in general.

Comment: The question is tagged as `linux` and `debian`.  My answer therefore refers to those systems, and not to, say, FreeBSD.